# Error with Intersection of two sets in Java

Tags: java, set, intersection

I am having a problem with intersection of two hashsets. I don't know why is 0 all the time and consequently, similarity value is 0.

Anyway I am posting the methods that envolves Intersection. The part corresponding to union is working fine. I would appreciate your help.

```
public <T> double Similarity (Set<T> s1, Set<T> s2){

    if (s1.isEmpty() || s2.isEmpty()){
        return 0.0;
    }
    double similarity;
    int unionValue;
    int intersectionValue;

    intersectionValue=intersection(s1, s2);
    unionValue=union(s1, s2);       
    similarity=(double)intersectionValue/(double)unionValue;

    System.out.println(unionValue+"    "+intersectionValue);
    System.out.println(similarity);

    return similarity;
}



public <T> int intersection (Set<T> s1, Set<T> s2){

    Set<T> intersection = new HashSet<T>(s1);
    intersection.retainAll(s2);
    return intersection.size();
}

public <T> int union (Set<T> s1, Set<T> s2){

    Set<T> union = new HashSet<T>(s1);
    union.addAll(s1);

    for (T apiSwRepo : s2){
        if (union.toString().contains(apiSwRepo.toString())){
        }
        else
            union.add(apiSwRepo);
    }
    return union.size();

}
```

Comment: Can we see ``union``? Also, can we see your test?

Comment: Sure, I added union.

Comment: Using `"a", "b", "c"` and `"a", "b", "d"` (two `HashSet<String>`, your code outputs the expected values for me (4 and 2). Can you show the test case you're using? Maybe something goes wrong there.

Comment: Let me make that test and tell post it. Because my test is just a litte complicated (with imports of Java projects)

Comment: @Chronio with those HashSet<String> works fine. So problem is definetely with my set. But union works fine with mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in your comparison.

```
if (union.toString().contains(apiSwRepo.toString())) {
} else
    union.add(apiSwRepo);
```

In the above code, you are converting the Set to a String and then calling contains().  You instead should be .contains() on the union itself like so:

```
if (union.contains(apiSwRepo)) {
} else
    union.add(apiSwRepo);
```

I'd also like to suggest a simplification as follows:

```
union.retainAll(s2);
```

Because you have two Sets, you will get the union from that simple statement.

Comment: I also commented a few issues with converting the `set` into a string on her own answer (probably below). The best solution is not just `union.addAll(s2);` I suggest to also do some mathematical comparison in order to get the real intersection size value. `addAll` by itself, will get all values in both sets, that's exactly why we have `retainAll` in place.

Comment: Oops! Sorry about that! You are obviously correct. I have corrected my code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason yet. But I solved it making this changes to intersection method:

```
public <T> int intersection (Set<T> s1,Set<T> s2){

    Set<T> intersection = new HashSet<T>();
    for (T apiSwRepo:s2){
        if (s1.toString().contains(apiSwRepo.toString())){
            intersection.add(apiSwRepo);
        }           
    }
  return intersection.size();
}
```

As you can see, I did not use the `intersection.retainAll` because with my data it did not work, but with `Set<String>` test, it did.

Just to be clear, my `data-set` was `API` information of a `HashMap`

`HashMap<Integer, Set<API>> apisPerSystem = new HashMap<Integer, Set<API>>()`

Comment: This has something wrong, you are actually converting the Set1 to a string, if `toSting` is not implemented in `<T>` it will not throw the desired value. Also, if you have a `Set<String>` and you have two values like `thisismyset` in `s1` and `myset` in `s2`, you will have an intersection that is not valid.